# App crashes when deploying spring mvc website to Heroku

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my spring mvc project to Heroku and I get the following errors:

```
2015-07-14T22:42:49.088312+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-07-14T22:42:49.101203+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-07-14T22:43:31.905877+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hops.herokuapp.com request_id=befdaefa-cb1e-4560-a190-c532a339531b fwd="70.73.71.223" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-07-14T22:43:32.769807+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hops.herokuapp.com request_id=c04566c1-7b09-4b45-8f64-497601415823 fwd="70.73.71.223" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I have tried running heroku run rails console but it gives me the following error:

```
Your version of git is 1.9.3. Which has serious security vulnerabilities.
More information here: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/12/23/update_your_git_clients_on_windows_and_os_x
Running `rails console` attached to terminal... up, run.8780
bash: rails: command not found
```

This is what my Procfile looks like:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

I have followed the instructions on this site, but I don't know how to get my website up and running.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-spring-mvc-hibernate#add-jetty-runner

Is there any other site that I can easily deploy my website or does anyone know how I can fix this error. Any help would be really appreciated.

**Update**

When running the foreman start web it shows the following output:

```
started with pid 7510
17:18:59 web.1  | Error: Unable to access jarfile target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar
17:18:59 web.1  | exited with code 1
17:18:59 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

The dependency for the jetty as display in the pom.xml is as follows:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-runner</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.16.v20140903</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I don't know how to fix this exactly or why its even creating this error.

Comment: What do your application logs say? Use `heroku logs --source app` to filter. Further, `rails console` won't be of use if you aren't running a Ruby on Rails app. You can get a remote shell via `heroku run bash` if you want to dig around your Heroku filesystem. Knowing a little more about what your app does (does it rely on a database? How is that configured?) would also help debug.

Comment: I tried running heroic logs --source app and all it says is that there are security vulnerabilities but doesn't say anything about errors. And for the remote shell I don't know what exactly to do. Is there any other sites that easy to deploy this type of project and don't ask for a credit card info?

Comment: I thought system ruby is pre-installed on a mac? If not how can I install it, to get to the root of my problem on this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you run your application locally with `foreman start web`?

Comment: I ran that command and it gave me the following error: Error: Unable to access jarfile target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar. I added jetty-runner as a dependency into my spring mvc pom.xml file like it said to do that on heroku.

Comment: `heroku run rails console` attempts to run the Ruby on Rails (rails is a framework for Ruby, like Spring is for Java) on *the Heroku side*. This won't help you as you're not running a Rails application.

How are you running your application locally? Via Tomcat? Jetty? Do you have a `.war` file or something else that you build? Compare your app layout and Procfile to the code the Heroku tutorial is based on: https://github.com/heroku/devcenter-spring-mvc-hibernate

Comment: I'm using spring tool suite to run the project and it uses pivotal tc server developer edition to run the website locally. The project is simply a spring/maven project that was made in STS.

Comment: @codefinger I added the error that gets displayed when running the command in my question above.

Comment: The pom.xml should have a plugin configured to copy the Jetty dependency from the Maven repository into the target directory. Sounds like this may be missing?

Comment: Yes, you probably need the plugin config here: https://github.com/kissaten/jetty-runner-minimal/blob/master/pom.xml#L20-L41

Comment: @codefinger Thank you so much I was missing the plugin, other than that it worked perfectly!!! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeating what's in the comment so this can be marked as answered.

You need to add the following plugin configuration:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
            <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jetty-runner</artifactId>
                        <version>9.2.7.v20150116</version>
                        <destFileName>jetty-runner.jar</destFileName>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

This will copy the jetty-runner into the slug so it can be used at runtime.